# Arithmetic expressions in words

Tags: conjunctions, compound-nouns, compound-subjects, measure-expressions

Consider the following sentences, which I know are correct, as example;

> Two multiplied by two gives four. **OR** Two times two gives four. **OR** Two by two gives four.
>
> Two divided by two is one.

**Q1:** Are the following variants of both the examples also grammatical and formally acceptable?

> Two multiplied two gives four. **OR** Two multiply two gives four.
>
> Two divided two is one. **OR** Two divide two is one. **OR** Two over two is one.

Now, consider the following common expressions;

> Two plus two makes four. **OR** Two and two make four.
>
> Two minus two is zero.

**Q2:** Are the following two variants of both the examples also grammatical and formally acceptable?

> Two added to two makes four. **OR** Two added two makes four.
>
> Two subtracted from two is zero. **OR** Two subtracted two is zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answers in bold caps.

> Two multiplied two gives four. **NO** OR Two multiply two gives four. **PROBABLY NO***
>
> Two divided two is one. **NO** OR Two divide two is one. **PROBABLY NO*** OR Two over two is one. **YES**
>
> Two added to two makes four. **YES** OR Two added two makes four. **NO**
>
> Two subtracted from two is zero. **YES** OR Two subtracted two is zero. **NO**

*I would not use the "PROBABLY NO" versions, but I am not 100% sure they're not used in some forms of non-standard English.

Comment: What is your reference to saying YES for two of them, please?

Comment: Those two, which you say YES to, definitely seem correct, but are they used that way in formal texts? I, personally, have never come across those two formations.

Comment: Well, it's a combination of being a native speaker and knowing what sounds 'natural' and the fact that the ones I have marked make grammatical sense as sentences. They might be considered more 'wordy', but in a more literary context (rather than, say, a maths text book) they might be the best choice.

Could they be used in formal texts? Yes, they are perfectly correct.

Comment: Those incorrect ones are, however, commonly used by non-native english speakers like me, and sometimes they sound right too even knowing they neither are grammatically correct. I thought, may be, they were also used by natives or in formats texts. ^^